# How to keep the state of bootcamp(As in taking a snapshot in VM) while logging back to os

Tags: macos, mac, virtual-machine, boot-camp

I am in a small dilemma. I mainly work under OSX. But from time to time, I need to use this specific program which is solely designed for windows. I have an iso copy of the program. So under windows 10, I can use the windows native virtual disk to open it. But every time I move back to OSX, I lose the program and have to reinstall it(or remount it? whichever is more accurate). Since I don't feel this small needs justifies the cost of a VM, I wonder if there is a way for bootcamp to take a snapshot of the OS that is similar to taking a snapshot in virtual box?

As for the reason of not using virtual box:setting up a VM is a bit tedious especially for windows, which I don't have an iso image at hand. and I am just too lazy to go through the process for a minor inconvenience.

Comment: Nope, OS X doesn't even know Windows exists when you're booted to it from Boot Camp - just use Parallels - it suspends on quit, resumes on launch; problem over.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the question. "I can use the windows native virtual disk to open it". What does that mean? Also your thinking is backwards from most people. If it's just one app that you only need to run once in a while, a VM is far more convenient that dedicating a bootcamp partition to it and rebooting the whole computer just to run it every now and then. Also VBox can be configured to use the bootcamp partiton. You wouldn't need to reinstall Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store the state of a running system across multiple boots, then you have to hibernate the OS. You CAN do this with Windows, though I'm not sure that's actually the best option for you. I recommend using VirtualBox, VMware Fusion or Parallels to virtualize Windows for you. You can then legitimately snapshot the system in the state you prefer. Also you can power-down the VM in a suspended state.